# Como criar um "Contador de linhas" em um texbox

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, textbox

Queria poder contar as linhas como no *Visual Code*, *atom* ou algum editor desse tipo.

Segue uma imagem de exemplo 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Detalhes: Meu projeto roda em c# form, um dos forms teria uma txtbox com o contador de linhas.

já adianto um obrigado!
edit : consegui , Usei a biblioteca https://sourceforge.net/projects/bsfccontrollibr/ e mudei as propriedades do projeto para .lib e compilei

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a biblioteca [Able Opus C#](https://sourceforge.net/projects/bsfccontrollibr/) lá você vai encontrar o componente `NumberedRTB`que é um `RichTextBox` com um painel numerado ao lado:

[image: NumberedRTB]

Para usá-lo basta instancia-lo em run-time ou então adicioná-lo em design-time via toolbox.

Para instanciar em runtime:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

// Para ter acesso ao controle insira o namespace
using AboControls.UserControls;



namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        // Crie uma instância do componente
        public NumberedRTB textBox1 = new NumberedRTB();

        public Form1()
        {           
            InitializeComponent();

            // Adicione o controle no Form
            this.Controls.Add(textBox1);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: olá Me ajudou muito, aproveitando a pergunta como faria o "import" pro meu projeto já existente ?

Comment: @fullstack-overkill: Compile a biblioteca e depois adicione-a como [referência](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2008/7314433t(v=vs.90))

Answer (score 3):

TLN.js / TLN.css

```js
const TLN = {
    eventList: {},
    update_line_numbers: function(ta, el) {
        let lines = ta.value.split("\n").length;
        let child_count = el.children.length;
        let difference = lines - child_count;

        if(difference > 0) {
            let frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
            while(difference > 0) {
                let line_number = document.createElement("span");
                line_number.className = "tln-line";
                frag.appendChild(line_number);
                difference--;
            }
            el.appendChild(frag);
        }
        while(difference < 0) {
            el.removeChild(el.firstChild);
            difference++;
        }
    },
    append_line_numbers: function(id) {
        let ta = document.getElementById(id);
        if(ta == null) {
            return console.warn("[tln.js] Couldn't find textarea of id '"+id+"'");
        }
        if(ta.className.indexOf("tln-active") != -1) {
            return console.warn("[tln.js] textarea of id '"+id+"' is already numbered");
        }
        ta.classList.add("tln-active");
        ta.style = {};

        let el = document.createElement("div");
        ta.parentNode.insertBefore(el, ta);
        el.className = "tln-wrapper";
        TLN.update_line_numbers(ta, el);
        TLN.eventList[id] = [];

        const __change_evts = [
            "propertychange", "input", "keydown", "keyup"
        ];
        const __change_hdlr = function(ta, el) {
            return function(e) {
                if((+ta.scrollLeft==10 && (e.keyCode==37||e.which==37
                    ||e.code=="ArrowLeft"||e.key=="ArrowLeft"))
                || e.keyCode==36||e.which==36||e.code=="Home"||e.key=="Home"
                || e.keyCode==13||e.which==13||e.code=="Enter"||e.key=="Enter"
                || e.code=="NumpadEnter")
                    ta.scrollLeft = 0;
                TLN.update_line_numbers(ta, el);
            }
        }(ta, el);
        for(let i = __change_evts.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            ta.addEventListener(__change_evts[i], __change_hdlr);
            TLN.eventList[id].push({
                evt: __change_evts[i],
                hdlr: __change_hdlr
            });
        }

        const __scroll_evts = [ "change", "mousewheel", "scroll" ];
        const __scroll_hdlr = function(ta, el) {
            return function() {  el.scrollTop = ta.scrollTop;  }
        }(ta, el);
        for(let i = __scroll_evts.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            ta.addEventListener(__scroll_evts[i], __scroll_hdlr);
            TLN.eventList[id].push({
                evt: __scroll_evts[i],
                hdlr: __scroll_hdlr
            });
        }
    },
    remove_line_numbers: function(id) {
        let ta = document.getElementById(id);
        if(ta == null) {
            return console.warn("[tln.js] Couldn't find textarea of id '"+id+"'");
        }
        if(ta.className.indexOf("tln-active") == -1) {
            return console.warn("[tln.js] textarea of id '"+id+"' isn't numbered");
        }
        ta.classList.remove("tln-active");

        ta.previousSibling.remove();

        if(!TLN.eventList[id]) return;
        for(let i = TLN.eventList[id].length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            const evt = TLN.eventList[id][i];
            ta.removeEventListener(evt.evt, evt.hdlr);
        }
        delete TLN.eventList[id];
    }
}
```

```css
.tln-active, .tln-wrapper, .tln-line {
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    outline: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    vertical-align: middle;
    list-style: none;
}
.tln-active {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    width: calc(100% - 48px);
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    font-family: "Roboto Mono", monospace;
    word-break: break-all;
    border: 1px solid #aeaeae;
    background-color: #fff;
    resize: none;
    overflow-wrap: normal;
    overflow-x: auto;
    white-space: pre;
}
.tln-wrapper {
    width: 48px;
    padding: 11px 5px 35px;
    height: 100%;
    word-break: break-all;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
    counter-reset: line;
    background: #ebebe4;
}
.tln-line {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    text-align: right;
    line-height: 1.5;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #aeaeae;
}
.tln-line::before {
    counter-increment: line;
    content: counter(line);
    font-size: 16px;
    user-select: none;
    color: #545454;
}
```

```html
<h1> Example </h1>
    <button onclick="TLN.append_line_numbers('test')"> NUMBERIFY! </button>
    <button onclick="TLN.remove_line_numbers('test')"> UN-NUMBERIFY! </button>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <textarea id="test" class="banana-cake"></textarea>
    </div>
    <label>
        Width:
        <input oninput="wrapper.style.width=this.value+'px';" type="range" value="500" min="100" max="700" />
    </label>
    <label>
        Height:
        <input oninput="wrapper.style.height=this.value+'px';" type="range" value="500" min="100" max="700" />
    </label>
```

Esse código não foi eu quem fiz, mas uso uma versão modificada do mesmo.
Segue o git da onde achei esse código.

https://github.com/MatheusAvellar/textarea-line-numbers

Comment: Oi, como eu poderia importar esse js para o meu projeto ?

Comment: Descreva mais sobre esse seu projeto, pois VS e uma IDE para desenvolvimento, quando deixa uma pergunta detalhe mais pois deixei uma resposta tendo em mente que estaria montando um site.. Obs: também sou novo em programação e assim como você faco meus projetos, e somente agora estou entrando aqui para ver se ajudo a galera mas sem mais detalhes posso te dar uma solução incoerente.

Comment: Acabei esquecendo de marcar, o projeto é o win c# form

Comment: @RafaelSene. Adicione a tag winform na pergunta.